# AngularJs Page Refresh Issue after removed hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="echo">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        // Other JS and CSS File
    </head>
    <body>
       <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

myapp.js

```
    myapp
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/studies.html',
        controller  : 'listStudyController'
    })
    .when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/dashboard.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/profile', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/profile.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    //check browser support
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled:true,
        requireBase:true
    });
});
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Note:
- Removed hash tag from url successfully.
- When I reloading page It display error.

**Not Found**
The requested URL /profile was not found on this server.

Comment: try to add `$locationProvider.hashprefix('');` just before your routes in your `myapp.js`

Comment: it's not working, I'm getting same error.

Comment: I got it. Edit "httpd-vhosts.conf" File and set this
<Directory /var/www/html>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
               AllowOverride All
               Order allow,deny
               allow from all
</Directory>

it works.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to the question and accept it so others in the same situration can use your solution :)

Comment: nice Idea, I posted. (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1:
Edit "httpd-vhosts.conf"
step 2:
Set

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
</Directory>
```

**AllowOverride All** is solved my problem.