# htaccess redirect not working for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, redirect

I know that I need a `.htaccess` file to redirect my AngularJS app after reloading/refreshing and not getting a 404.
I am using **AngularJS 1.5.7**

My htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

With this in `.htaccess` I got rid of the 404, but after refreshing the page angular isn't rendering the HTML anymore. Also tried different versions of `rewriteconditions`

In my app config I am using:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

I can't spot the error by myself.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting `<base>` on the HTML doc?

Comment: See this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596063/angularjs-page-refresh-issue-after-removed-hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596063/angularjs-page-refresh-issue-after-removed-hash)

Comment: Yes I did try it, but doesn't work either that's why I set `requireBase` to `false` @MasterPo