# How to remove # from Angular App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, amazon-ec2, apache2, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an Angular Application (Angular 5) as well as Ruby on rails backend. I put my angular app in the ruby-on-rails public folder and its working fine with a '#' prefix.

Now, I want to remove that '#' Prefix. When I remove it, I am getting errors.

I've deploy ruby-on-rails application on EC2 with Apache2 and Passenger.

This is my PATH for .htaccess file

```
/var/www/ro-blog/.htaccess
```

Can anyone please help me - How can I fix that?

Comment: You need to use the `$locationProvider` module and set `html5Mode` to **true**.

Comment: @Emu can you give me any URL or settings that I can.

Comment: @ochs.tobi I write that code already - .htaccess but still not working.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/28629981/3085279

Comment: Can you show also index of your index.html?

Comment: @TanDuong I think that is for Angular 1 and I have Angular 5.

Comment: I face this issue before, this is work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596063/angularjs-page-refresh-issue-after-removed-hash